# jQuery Datepicker not getting minDate from this min attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am I missing something wholly obvious here?

### Html

```
<input class="datepicker" min="2014-10-22" name="start_date" type="text" value="2014-11-22" id="start_date">
```

### Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: $(this).attr('min'),
        // minDate: '2014-10-22',
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function() {
            console.log($(this).attr('min'));
        }
    });
});
```

onSelect shows it's getting the min attribute correctly. But minDate seems to be ignoring it.

If I hardcode it then it works, but if I use `minDate: $(this).attr('min'),` then no minDate is set.

Comment: because in that context `this` doesn't refer the `input` element

Comment: You can use $(this).prop("tagName") to check which element you are referring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are calling `$(this).attr('min')` inside the dom ready callback, where `this` refers to the document object not the `input` element.

If there is only one datepicker in the page you can change it to `$('.datepicker').attr('min')`.

But if there are more than 1 then

```js
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
      minDate: $(this).attr('min'),
      // minDate: '2014-10-22',
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      onSelect: function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('min'));
      }
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input class="datepicker" min="2014-10-22" name="start_date" type="text" value="2014-11-22" id="start_date">
<input class="datepicker" min="2014-11-22" name="start_date" type="text" value="2014-11-22" id="end_date">
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, thanks for clarifying that. I was sure this referred to the input but obviously only inside option callbacks. That works perfectly. Much appreciated.